# Civilization 6 add City States in World Builder

Tags: civilization-modding

There are instructions to access the Civ 6 Worldbuilder in [civfanatics forums](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/how-to-launch-the-ingame-worldbuilder.600327/#post-14517066).

The TZ mod method allows starting with a custom map, but there are no generated city states.

How can I add city states to the map / mod so the game does not crash on the first turn?

Comment: It sounds like you might get better answers on the civ modding forum where you found these instructions originally. Very few game developers here are also experienced Civ 6 modders, so while your question is not off-topic, it's less likely to find the right experts here.

Answer (score 1):

### Meeting the original criteria: no crash

It seems the city state must be **random**. Specific city states seem to crash.

Step by step:

1. Add CS starting position (random) on map.
2. Go to top left corner "Player Editor".
3. Set civilization level to `CIVILIZATION_LEVEL_CITY_STATE`
4. Leave selected cilization at `Random`.

However the map editor only allows adding up to 10 players.

### More City States

A good way of getting past the limit is installing [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org) and using that to edit the map file.
Change the last players to `CIVILIZATION_LEVEL_CITY_STATE` and you will get more city states on the map. :)